# Ansible unable to create folder on localhost with different user

Tags: ssh, ansible, sudo, ansible-inventory

I'm executing ansible playbook with `appuser` whereas I wish to create folder with user `webuser` on localhost.

ssh keys are setup for webuser on my localhost. So after login with `appuser` I can simply `ssh webuser@localhost` to switch user to `webuser`.

Note: I do not have sudo priveledges so I cannot `sudo` to switch to webuser from appuser.

Below is my playbook that is run with user appuser but needs to create a folder `04May2020` on localhost using `webuser`

```
- name: "Play 1"

  hosts: localhost
  remote_user: "webuser"
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /app/misc_automation/ssh_keys_id_rsa

  tasks:
   - name: create folder for today's print
     file:
       path: "/webWeb/htdocs/print/04May2020"
       state: directory
     remote_user: webuser
```

However, the output shows that the folder is created with `appuser` instead of `webuser`. See output showing ssh connectivity with `appuser` instead of `webuser`.

```
ansible-playbook /app/Ansible/playbook/print_oracle/print.yml -i /app/Ansible/playbook/print_oracle/allhosts.hosts -vvv

TASK [create folder for today] ***********************************
task path: /app/Ansible/playbook/print_oracle/print.yml:33
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/files/file.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: appuser
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python2 && sleep 0'
```

Can you please suggest if it is possible without `sudo`?

Comment: Please show your localhost definition in /app/Ansible/playbook/print_oracle/allhosts.hosts

Comment: There is no entry for localhost or local IP in /app/Ansible/playbook/print_oracle/allhosts.hosts

Comment: If there is no entry anywhere, localhost is implicit and using the local connection. If it uses ssh there must be a dfinition of localhost somewhere. And I bet it is also defined to use the `appuser` which overrides what you define at playbook or task time.

Comment: There is no entry of `appuser` anywhere except the fact that i run the playbook using `appuser`

Comment: Oups, getting tired... and reading too fast.... sorry ! Let's start again. You are connecting to localhost though the [implicit localhost definition](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html) which uses the local connection (as indicated by the line `<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: appuser`). Changing the remote_user has no effect on the local connection. You need to change the user launching the playbook.

Comment: One other solution is to declare an other host as e.g. `localssh ansible_host=127.0.0.1` and target you play to it. In this case, the playbook will use an ssh connection and will use the remote_user to connect.

Comment: i made an entry [localserver] 10.9.9.33 in the host file (10.9.9.33 being my localhost's IP) and then gave `host: localserver` and now remote_user kicks in and works fine. However, when I'm not dealing with localserver and using delegate_to: localhost then remote_user does not kick in. How can we get a different user to work when a particular task executed using `delegate_to` ?

Comment: You have created a group, not a host. Change your definition to `localserver ansible_host=10.9.9.33`. You can now use is as a target and delegate to it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting all my comments together in a comprehensive answer.

> <127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: appuser

This is indicating that you are connecting to localhost through the [`local` connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/local.html), either because you explicitelly re-declared the host as such or because you are using the [implicit localhost](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html). From discussions, you are in the second situation.

When using the `local` connection plugin, as indicated in the above documentation, the `remote_user` is ignored. Trying to change the user has no effect as you can see in the below test run (user (u)ids changed):

```sh
# Check we are locally running as user1
$ id -a
uid=xxxx(user1) gid=yyy(group1) groups=yyy(group1)
# Running the same command through ansible returns the same result
$ ansible localhost -a 'id -a'
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
uid=xxxx(user1) gid=yyy(group1) groups=yyy(group1)
# Trying to change the remote user has no effect
$ ansible localhost -u whatever -a 'id -a'
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
uid=xxxx(user1) gid=yyy(group1) groups=yyy(group1)
```

Without changing your playbook and/or inventory, the only solution is to launch the playbook as the user who needs to create the directory.

Since you have ssh available, an other solution is to declare a new host that you will use only for this purpose, which will target the local IP through ssh. (Note: you can explicitly declare `localhost` like this but then all connections will go through ssh which might not be what you want to do).

Somewhere at the top of you inventory, add the line:

```
localssh ansible_host=127.0.0.1
```

And in your playbook, change

```
hosts: localssh
```

Now the connection to your local machine will go through ssh and the `remote_user` will be obeyed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can try is by setting the ansible_connection to localhost. To do this, in the directory from which you are running ansible commands, create a host_vars directory. In that sub-directory, create a file named localhost, containing the line ansible_connection: smart

Comment: Note that, from my quick test, this has the same effect as setting connection to ssh which will make all connection go through this plugin even when delegating without needing to change remote_user.